# Entity Namespace does not appear in Silverlight project

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, namespaces, models, ria

I have a Silverlight web project where I apply the MVVM pattern. In my entire solution I have 4 projects.

Project "A3", which contains all of my Views and ViewModels.

Project "A3.Web", which contains my main html files, images, sound files, etc.

Project "A3Lib", which contains my XAML binding converters and other helpful classes that I created.

Project "A3Lib.Web", which contains the Data Models and Domain Logic.

All of my entity models are inside my DataModels folder and all of my Domain Service server side code is inside the DomainLogic folder. I created a new folder inside the DataModels folder named "Common".

So when I want to add the data model to my VM, I tried "using A3Lib.Web.DataModels.Common;" and that did not find the namespace.

Issue: when I add a new folder and a new entity model to the DataModels folder, I do not see the namespace in my View or ViewModel in the "A3" project.

However, I already have existing code there (was added by someone else) and the models he added show perfectly fine (when doing using ...... in the View or VM).

I checked web.config to make sure the connection string is there and it's correct. I also tried to add a brand new context to the base class of the project (where other contexts are) and that did not help. My project simply cannot resolve or see the data model namespace that I create.

Thanks

Yura

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Silverlight app sees the models and namespaces from the server-side project through the generated code - you should see it in the Generated_Code folder of your A3Lib project.  If it is not there, then the proxy classes are not being generated on build.  A couple things to check:

1. class is not private (hey - sometimes it's the simple things)
2. if using Domain Services, the service needs to have at least 1 method that returns an IQueryable or IEnumerable (even if method returns null) in order to see the class in the Silverlight-side domaincontext
3. if the class is just a utility class that you want to share with the client, save the file as classname.shared.cs, and the proxy will pick it up.
4. make sure the project references are to the projects and not (possibly older) .dlls in another location.

That's all I've got based on the info provided.